# What's wrong with my comparator

Tags: comparator, hysteresis

I'm trying to set up a comparator that goes high when the input is above 0V and goes low when the input is below -5V. I've used the datasheet equations to calculate the resistors for a non-inverting comparator dual supply (+/-12V) and -5V as Vref, but when I try to simulate it both in ltspice and circuit I just get a tiny echo of the input at the output. Is something wrong with my circuit?

Pinout of LM393 symbol is 1 = non-inverting input 2 = inverting input 3 = positive supply 4 = negative supply 5 = open collector output
[image]

Comment: Please correct the text in your opening lines i.e. "when the output is above 0V" and "output is below -5V". Also name the device used and show power rails used.

Comment: You forgot to add the device part number in your edit. Is that an LTSpice schematic?

Comment: The actual circuit uses LM393. That model isn't available in LTspice, so I've been using LT1011 which is similar to LM311 and LM393.

Comment: What is pin 1 of the LT1011 connected to?

Comment: @Jon, please edit your question to include **all** the relevant information. Don't bury it in the comments where it will be missed. Show the circuit from your simulation, not some other drawing that's similar.

Comment: @Transistor I've found a way to model LM393 and included the LTSpice screen capture in the post. The symbol is just a bit funky.

Comment: I can't find that LM393 pinout anywhere on the web. Have you got a datasheet link? (Again, pop it into the question.)

Comment: On LM393 pin 1 is the output.  Is this what you mean by a bit funky?

Comment: [Data sheet link](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm2903)

Comment: Updated the post with the pinout for the symbol. I just followed the model nomenclature which does not match the pinout of the actual part. Yes that is why it's funky

Comment: I calculate V(TL) to be -17 V with those resistors.  I would expect to see the output sitting at around 12 V with very small drops when the pulse goes negative.

Comment: @evildemonic OK, I've actually been able to get the LM393 model to work with a single supply so I know it's not the model now and I need to wrap my head around this dual supply hysteresis. Thanks

Comment: Here are the equations I used to evaluate your circuit:  $$V_{TH}=((100\ kΩ+140\ kΩ)\times\text{-}5\ V - (100\ kΩ \times \text{-}12\ V))\div140\ kΩ=0\ V$$ and $$V_{TL}=((100\ kΩ+140\ kΩ)\times\text{-}5\ V - (100\ kΩ \times 12\ V))\div140\ kΩ=\text{-}17.14\ V$$

Comment: Ah OK, I see where I made my error. I only did calculations for Vth and assumed that Vref set Vtl. Rookie mistake

Comment: Is this related to the deleted question today?  If you can come to grips with the real purpose and specifications of this problem, the solution can be trivial, but so far it is twisted by your suggested inexperienced implementation.  THat's what it tells me. Not trying to mean, but you aren't listening.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Seriously? You're stalking my posts? The only thing I learned here is that this forum is a cesspool for EEs who get off on lording over and ridiculing anyone who doesn't have their caliber of engineering skill. Guess I'll be deleting my account and going elsewhere in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon When you learn to specify knowns, unknowns inputs and outputs for even simple functions like a trivial comparator and I was looking for clues to you lacking answers, I can only conclude you have too much to learn, like a proper attitude.  Check your ego at the door on your way out.

Comment: I expected something like  Given +/-12V, 1% and input 10 mV to 5.5V  , define a comparator with non-inverting feature and ~ 5V hysteresis but critically set to x mV above 0Vdc.. Output 0 to 12V drives 1mA linear load , BW< 1MHz, room temp, Qty=1

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I do have a lot to learn. I didn't cop an attitude until you called my responses 'dumb'. I didn't ask for a detailed explanation of the various parameters to consider when designing a schmitt trigger circuit. Just one detail that would help me on my path to learning about them on my terms and in chunks I can comprehend easily. Other details were optional. I think I arrived at that answer on my own, but it's nice to have a resource to accelerate that process or have things reiterated in a way that makes more sense at times. Maybe this is not that place?